# 2amigos Google Map Api Printing Out Coordinates

Tags: php, html, google-maps-api-3, yii2

I'm struggling to work out why this is happening. My code for the Google Map is working fine which is the below

```html
<div class="site-about">
  <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?=
  $coord = new LatLng(['lat' => 53.041880, 'lng' => -2.185166]);

  $map = new Map([
    'center' => $coord,
    'zoom' => 16,
  ]);
  echo $map->display(); ?>
</div>
```

However when it renders on the page, I get not only the google map viewport but I also get a print out of the lat and lng above the map like below:

[Image showing map and coords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKAkl.png)

Any ideas as to why this is being printed out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<?=
```

To

```
<?PHP
```

Because with the equal sign you're printing the $coord var

Comment: Brilliant this was the fix! Much appreciated!